# Who is the prophet in Matthew 1:22?

Tags: matthew

I have a feeling that Isaiah is the prophet mentioned in Matthew 1:22. There is no reference to who this prophet is for some unknown reason.

Does anyone have any info or deniable proof of this? Is Isaiah the prophet mentioned in this verse?

Matthew 1:22, 23 NIV

> <sup>**22**</sup> All this took place to fulfill what the Lord had said through the prophet: <sup>**23**</sup> “The virgin will conceive and give birth to a son, and they will call him Immanuel” (which means “God with us”).

Comment: Related questions: [Does Isaiah 7:14 refer to a virgin?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/17042/3555) and [What were the translators of the LXX thinking in rendering “virgin” in Isaiah 7:14?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13165/3555).

Comment: @Susan- What is your view on the subject?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly, but if you want to chat, [The Library](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) would be the best place. Feel free to drop in. Here on the main site we stick with specific questions and focused answers rather than discussion.

Comment: Please [edit] this to quote from your preferred translation. And there is no doubt that it is Isaiah, it is a direct quote from Isaiah 7:14.

Answer (score 1):

**Isaiah** is the prophet in question. Your Bible will probably have a footnote beside the quotation which will show you where it comes from:

> *All this took place to fulfill what the Lord had spoken by **the prophet**:
>   “Behold, the virgin shall conceive and bear a son,
>       and they shall call his name Immanuel”* - Matthew 1:22-23 (ESV)
>
> *"Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign. Behold, the virgin shall conceive and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel."* - **Isaiah 7:14** (ESV)

Answer (score 0):

Christian Bible The lord will give you a sign (Virgin conception?) the king is going to see that? Isaiah is telling him that why worry about an attack they will be gone 700 years from now. The sign is the marking of time. Isaiah's second son Immanuel (see chapter 8) marks when the kingdoms will be gone. I believe the Dead sea Isaiah scroll.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51048)